# useState leads to infinite rendering - understanding the solution

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a weird issue which occurs in very few lines of code, and I do not understand what's happening in the back of the scenes.

I have the following 4 lines of code:

```
function FarmerComponent(props) {
  let authCtx = useContext(AuthContext)
  let usersAndItemsCtx = useContext(usersAndProductsContext)
  
  let current_logged_user = usersAndItemsCtx.usersVal.find(user => user.id === authCtx.currentLoggedUserId);

  let [isCurrentFarmerLikedFlag, isCurrentFarmerLikedFlagToggle] = useState(false)
  console.log(current_logged_user.likedProfilesId)
    let flag = (current_logged_user.likedProfilesId.find((id) =>id === props.id) ? true : false)
    isCurrentFarmerLikedFlagToggle(flag);
    console.log(flag)
```

this produces for me the following error:

> react-dom.development.js:16317 Uncaught Error: Too many re-renders.
> React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop.
> at renderWithHooks (react-dom.development.js:16317:1)
> at updateFunctionComponent (react-dom.development.js:19588:1)
> at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:21601:1)
> at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:4164:1)
> at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:4213:1)
> at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:4277:1)
> at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:27451:1)
> at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:26557:1)
> at workLoopSync (react-dom.development.js:26466:1)
> at renderRootSync (react-dom.development.js:26434:1)

while also logs many times 'false'.

Now, if I change these lines as the following:

```
function FarmerComponent(props) {
  let authCtx = useContext(AuthContext)
  let usersAndItemsCtx = useContext(usersAndProductsContext)
  
  let current_logged_user = usersAndItemsCtx.usersVal.find(user => user.id === authCtx.currentLoggedUserId);

  console.log(current_logged_user.likedProfilesId)
  let flag = (current_logged_user.likedProfilesId.find((id) =>id === props.id) ? true : false)
  console.log(flag)
  let [isCurrentFarmerLikedFlag, isCurrentFarmerLikedFlagToggle] = useState(flag)
```

everything works like a charm.

Why would that even happen? de facto, nothing I'm aware of has changed.. so why such a drastic difference in the result ?

Regards

Comment: You're setting state at the top level of the component which means react will infinitely restart the render cycle. It is an issue because the component will never render (thus your error)

Comment: what do you mean by that and why would that be an issue? O_o

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Updating state to the same state directly in the component body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74034014/updating-state-to-the-same-state-directly-in-the-component-body)

Comment: *'...nothing I'm aware of has changed'* except you've removed a function call which is exactly what was causing the situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> de facto, nothing I'm aware of has changed

The thing that's changed is that you're no longer calling your state setter (`isCurrentFarmerLikedFlagToggle`) at the top level of your function component. You can't call state setters at the top level of a function component (even if you're [setting the same value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74034014/updating-state-to-the-same-state-directly-in-the-component-body), but in your case, you may not be, it could have changed between renders), because the function component is called during the render phase, which must be pure (other than scheduling side effects to happen later).

But there's a more fundamental issue: there's no need for that flag to be in state at all. Copying stateful information the component receives (as props, as context, etc.) into component state is, in general, an antipattern ([more here](https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/06/07/you-probably-dont-need-derived-state.html)). In your example, you don't need `isCurrentFarmerLikedFlag` to be a state member; it's value is derived purely from information your component is already being provided: `authCtx.currentLoggedUserId` and `usersAndItemsCtx.likedProfilesId`:

```
let authCtx = useContext(AuthContext);
let usersAndItemsCtx = useContext(usersAndProductsContext);

let current_logged_user = usersAndItemsCtx.usersVal.find(
    (user) => user.id === authCtx.currentLoggedUserId
);

let isCurrentFarmerLikedFlag = current_logged_user.likedProfilesId.find((id) => id === props.id) ? true : false;
//  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

**If** you thought the work involved in determining that value was too much to do on every render, you can [memoize](https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/06/07/you-probably-dont-need-derived-state.html#what-about-memoization) the value via [`useMemo`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usememo) (or any of various other memoization helpers):

```
let authCtx = useContext(AuthContext);
let usersAndItemsCtx = useContext(usersAndProductsContext);

let current_logged_user = useMemo(
    () => usersAndItemsCtx.usersVal.find((user) => user.id === authCtx.currentLoggedUserId),
    [authCtx.currentLoggedUserId, usersAndItemsCtx.usersVal]
);
let isCurrentFarmerLikedFlag = useMemo(
    () => (current_logged_user.likedProfilesId.find((id) => id === props.id) ? true : false),
    [current_logged_user.likedProfilesId]
);
```

*(More notes on that code below.)*

The callback calculates the value, and the dependency array tells `useMemo` when it should call the callback again because something changed. Anything you use directly in the calculation should be listed in the dependency array. (But note that there's no need to list the container something comes from; we have `authCtx.currentLoggeduserId` in the first dependency array above, for instance, not both `authCtx` *and* `authCtx.currentLoggeduserId`. We don't care if `authCtx` changed but `authCtx.currentLoggeduserId` didn't, because we don't use `authCtx` except for its `authCtx.currentLoggeduserId` value.)

---

A few side notes:

- While you can (of course) use any naming convention you like in your own code, I urge you to follow standard practice when writing code you'll share with others. The standard practice for naming state setters is that they have the name of the state variable (with its first letter capitalized) prefixed with the word `set`. So if the flag is `isCurrentFarmerLikedFlag`, the setter should be `setIsCurrentFarmerLikedFlag`. (Separately, `isCurrentFarmerLikedFlagToggle` is a particularly problematic name because it *doesn't* toggle the value, it accepts a new value to set [which may or may not be toggled.])
- This code:

  ```
  current_logged_user.likedProfilesId.find((id) => id === props.id) ? true : false
  ```

  can more succinctly and idiomatically be written *(but keep reading)*:

  ```
  current_logged_user.likedProfilesId.some((id) => id === props.id)
  ```

  Any time you want to just know *if* an array has an element that matches the predicate function you pass in, you can use [`some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) rather than `find`. **But**, since you don't actually need a predicate function at all (you're just checking for the direct existence of a value), we can go even further and use [`includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes):

  ```
  current_logged_user.likedProfilesId.includes(props.id)
  ```

3. All of the `let` declarations in that code could be `const` instead, and I'd urge you to use `const` because directly modifying their values (`isCurrentFarmerLikedFlag = newValue`) won't work and is misleading.

Taking all of that into account:

```
const authCtx = useContext(AuthContext);
const usersAndItemsCtx = useContext(usersAndProductsContext);

const current_logged_user = useMemo(
    () => usersAndItemsCtx.usersVal.find((user) => user.id === authCtx.currentLoggedUserId),
    [authCtx.currentLoggedUserId, usersAndItemsCtx.usersVal]
);
const isCurrentFarmerLikedFlag = useMemo(
    () => current_logged_user.likedProfilesId.includes(props.id),
    [current_logged_user.likedProfilesId]
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem was the calling function `isCurrentFarmerLikedFlagToggle` without any condition so, every time when your component renders, you also update the state which results in the rendering of your components again and again.

```
function FarmerComponent(props) {
  let authCtx = useContext(AuthContext)
  let usersAndItemsCtx = useContext(usersAndProductsContext)
  
  let current_logged_user = usersAndItemsCtx.usersVal.find(user => user.id === authCtx.currentLoggedUserId);

  let [isCurrentFarmerLikedFlag, isCurrentFarmerLikedFlagToggle] = useState(false)
  console.log(current_logged_user.likedProfilesId)
    let flag = (current_logged_user.likedProfilesId.find((id) =>id === props.id) ? true : false)
    isCurrentFarmerLikedFlagToggle(flag); // calling the function right after
    console.log(flag)
```

and when you did not call it like that, it works fine as your below code.

```
function FarmerComponent(props) {
  let authCtx = useContext(AuthContext)
  let usersAndItemsCtx = useContext(usersAndProductsContext)
  
  let current_logged_user = usersAndItemsCtx.usersVal.find(user => user.id === authCtx.currentLoggedUserId);

  console.log(current_logged_user.likedProfilesId)
  let flag = (current_logged_user.likedProfilesId.find((id) =>id === props.id) ? true : false)
  console.log(flag)
  let [isCurrentFarmerLikedFlag, isCurrentFarmerLikedFlagToggle] = useState(flag) // using the flag for initial value of state in useState
```