# Why React goes Infinite when I set state in function body?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, frontend, setstate

If we set the state with the same value component won't re-render, but it's not applicable when I set the state in the function body.

For example, if I set the same state on the button click and the button clicked, the component does not re-rendering on the button click

```
function Test1() {
  const [name, setName] = useState("Shiva");
  const onButtonClick = () => {
    console.log("Clicked");
    setName("Shiva");
  };
  console.log("Redering");
  return (
    <div>
      <span>My name is {name}</span>
      <button onClick={onButtonClick}>Click Me</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

But, when I set the same state before the return statement React goes infinite renderings

```
function Test2() {
  const [name, setName] = useState("Shiva");
  // ... come stuff
  setName("Shiva");
  console.log("Rendering");
  return (
    <div>
      <span>My name is {name}</span>
    </div>
  );
}
```

What actually happening internally?

Comment: No, I'm asking why the component is not re-rendered when I set the same state on the button click and why it's re-render if set before the return statement.

Comment: @Shiva it does, when set state is called in the main body of the function it gets executed during the render. When the set state is defined inside the click function, that click function is just _defined_ during the render, it's not actually executed until you click the button. So set state is not called until button is clicked, as opposed to during the render

Comment: hi @Jayce444, even I click on the button in the above example < Test1 /> component is not getting re-rendered.

Comment: @Shiva ohh right, thought you were asking about something else. So the reason it won't log "rendering" when you click the button is because the state doesn't actually change. It's initial value is "Shiva" and you change it to "Shiva", no difference. So under the hood React optimises state changes by doing shallow comparisons of old/new state value when doing a state change. If state hasn't changed, there's no point in re-rendering, so it doesn't

Comment: @Jayce444, I understand why the component not re-rendering on the button click happens, my question is why this same behavior is not applicable when we set the state in the direct function body as in <Test2 />.  Here also we are setting the same value right? if it is the same value why is the component getting re-rendering infinite times?

Comment: This is a very interesting question. I'd take a guess that it's to do with React's state tracking and where you're calling `setName()`. When you call it before the render (aka the `return` value), React probably hasn't had a chance to track the value so it's always triggering a re-render

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Updating state to the same state directly in the component body](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74034014)

Comment: @NickParsons, thank you so much for the comment. Yes, it's the same question. """It's triggering a rerender during the "Render phase". The React component never got a chance to complete a render cycle so there's nothing to "diff" against or bail out of, thus the render loop occurs.""" this is the answer there. My doubt is if React has nothing to compare which is already rendered, does go to infinite? what's the logic behind it?

Comment: You probably only ever want to change component state as a result of some event.

Comment: You call `setName` on render phase which schedule a state update which mean another render phase, again in that render phase you call `setName` again which schedule another render phase. Its goes like that

Answer (score 7):

React uses different approaches to schedule updates based on the place where you called your `setState`.

For example, your `setState` inside the event handler will use

```
export function enqueueConcurrentHookUpdate<S, A>(
  fiber: Fiber,
  queue: HookQueue<S, A>,
  update: HookUpdate<S, A>,
  lane: Lane,
)
```

While your `setState` in component top level use

```
function enqueueRenderPhaseUpdate<S, A>(
  queue: UpdateQueue<S, A>,
  update: Update<S, A>,
)
```

---

When you call `setState`, React will internally call a function,

```
function dispatchSetState<S, A>(
  fiber: Fiber,
  queue: UpdateQueue<S, A>,
  action: A,
)
```

If you check the declaration of this function, you will find a top level conditional check,

```
  if (isRenderPhaseUpdate(fiber)) {
    enqueueRenderPhaseUpdate(queue, update);
  } else {}
```

Your `setState` inside the event handler will use the `else` block while the `setState` in render phase ( top level function body ) will use `if` block.

---

**Additional**

so how does React decided whether its in render phase or not ? If you check the code of the `isRenderPhaseUpdate` you can see,

```
function isRenderPhaseUpdate(fiber: Fiber) {
  const alternate = fiber.alternate;
  return (
    fiber === currentlyRenderingFiber ||
    (alternate !== null && alternate === currentlyRenderingFiber)
  );
}
```

Now you might heard about virtual DOM, actually its a linked list. Each object of the linked list is known as fiber nodes. these fiber nodes are nothing more than plain javascript objects. Each of these fiber nodes has a field called, `alternate`.

There can be 2 separate fiber trees ( virtual doms ). One of this fiber tree is know as current tree which is the one committed to the DOM. The other fiber tree is known as the work-in-tree. This is the one react builds newly when states updates happens yet not committed to the DOM.

So for a given Component there can be maximum two fiber nodes ( one from current tree & another one from work-in-tree ). These two fiber nodes are connected using `alternate` field.

`currentlyRenderingFiber` is a global variable which keep track the currently rendering fiber node by React.

Now you should able to understand the body of above `isRenderPhaseUpdate` function.

**Additional Explanation Ends**

---

#### CASE 01 - Event Handler

When you trigger the `setState` from event handler react will use `else` block of the above function.

If you check the body of the `else` block you will find out following code snippet,

```
const currentState: S = (queue.lastRenderedState: any);
  const eagerState = lastRenderedReducer(currentState, action);
  update.hasEagerState = true;
  update.eagerState = eagerState;
  if (is(eagerState, currentState)) { // <-- checks if the previous value is equal to current one.
     enqueueConcurrentHookUpdateAndEagerlyBailout(fiber, queue, update);
     return; // <-- return early without call `enqueueConcurrentHookUpdate`
  }
  // never reaches here if the `eagerState` & `currentState` are same
  const root = enqueueConcurrentHookUpdate(fiber, queue, update, lane);
  if (root !== null) {
    const eventTime = requestEventTime();
    scheduleUpdateOnFiber(root, fiber, lane, eventTime);
    entangleTransitionUpdate(root, queue, lane);
  }
```

As you can see when `is(eagerState, currentState)` true ( Which is true in your case as both `eagerState` & `currentState` holds the value `"Shiva"` ) React will exit from the function early without calling `enqueueConcurrentHookUpdate`. This is why React won't re render for the same value again.

#### CASE 02 - Top level of the component

When you call `setState` from the top level of your component, it will run when React is traversing the component tree and calling your components ( due the execution of component body by React )

> Notice that React is the one who call your components. You are just defining them. React call your components and get the output when traversing aka when rendering & building the new fiber tree ( aka work-in-progress tree )

Now if you check the body of

```
function enqueueRenderPhaseUpdate<S, A>(
  queue: UpdateQueue<S, A>,
  update: Update<S, A>,
) {
  // This is a render phase update. Stash it in a lazily-created map of
  // queue -> linked list of updates. After this render pass, we'll restart
  // and apply the stashed updates on top of the work-in-progress hook.
  didScheduleRenderPhaseUpdateDuringThisPass = didScheduleRenderPhaseUpdate = true;
  const pending = queue.pending;
  if (pending === null) {
    // This is the first update. Create a circular list.
    update.next = update;
  } else {
    update.next = pending.next;
    pending.next = update;
  }
  queue.pending = update;
}
```

Notice the code comment of the above function. It creates a circular linked list of schedule updates causes from the `setState` in your component top level body.

According to the code comment, these stashed updates in the circular linked list will apply to the hook in your latest fiber node

Now notice the line in function `enqueueRenderPhaseUpdate`,

```
didScheduleRenderPhaseUpdateDuringThisPass = didScheduleRenderPhaseUpdate = true;
```

`didScheduleRenderPhaseUpdateDuringThisPass` is a global variable. This variable is use for a while loop,

```
do {
    didScheduleRenderPhaseUpdateDuringThisPass = false;

    if (numberOfReRenders >= RE_RENDER_LIMIT) {
      throw new Error(
        'Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent ' +
          'an infinite loop.',
      );
    }
    numberOfReRenders += 1;

    // some other code

    children = Component(props, secondArg);
  } while (didScheduleRenderPhaseUpdateDuringThisPass);
```

Each time your component body get executed ( `Component(props, secondArg);` in while loop), you are triggering `enqueueRenderPhaseUpdate` due to the `setState` in your component body which sets `didScheduleRenderPhaseUpdateDuringThisPass` to `true` which triggers the `while` loop again which calls the `Component` again.

Once the loop executed 25 times, React will throw an error.

You can find these function in,

1. `\react\packages\react-reconciler\src\ReactFiberHooks.new.js` ( [line 2538](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/main/packages/react-reconciler/src/ReactFiberHooks.new.js#L2538) )
2. `\react\packages\react-reconciler\src\ReactFiberHooks.old.js`

Answer (score 3):

`React` uses virtual DOM to update the changes into view. Virtual DOM has the rendered state when the component is rendered into view, that is after the execution of `return` statement in a functional component.

### Component Test1:

```js
function Test1() {
    const [name, setName] = useState("Shiva");
    const onButtonClick = () => {
        // State updates on button click happens after component gets rendered in view
        setName("Shiva");
    };
    return (
        <div>
            <span>My name is {name}</span>
            <button onClick={onButtonClick}>Click Me</button>
        </div>
    );
}
```

In the above example, by the time `return` statement is executed, functional component has been rendered in view, thus `React` has updated the rendered state in it's virtual DOM for tracking during upcoming state updates. Button click event cannot occur before the component gets rendered in view, thus `React` is aware of rendered state, and can track changes in state to process re-rendering of component.

### Component Test2:

```js
function Test2() {
    const [name, setName] = useState("Shiva");
    // State updates before component gets rendered
    setName("Shiva");
    return (
        <div>
            <span>My name is {name}</span>
        </div>
    );
}
```

In the above example, state is updated before the component gets rendered into the view, thus `React` has not yet updated it's virtual DOM with rendered state, thus there is no rendered state to track the changes. This triggers infinite re-rendering.