# Extra console.log from component body despite state not changing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

```
export const App = (props) => {
  const [data, setData] = useState(0)
  console.log(data)
  const onClick = () => {
    setData(1)
  }
  return <button onClick={onClick}>button</button>
}
```

From the above example, When I click button more than 2 times, I got result.

And also this code is not in `<StrictMode>`

0
1
1
('1' printed twice even though setState same value)

Reproduced here ~ https://codesandbox.io/s/bold-glitter-zphpwr?file=/src/App.js

You can see that the render count doesn't increase but there's one extra log line for `console.log("1: ", data)`

Same result in below example.

```
export const App = (props) => {
  const [data, setData] = useState(0)
  console.log(data)
  useEffect(() => {
    setData(1)
  }, [data])

  return <></>
}
```

and In other case below, I got infinite loop.

```
export const App = (props) => {
  const [data, setData] = useState(0)
  console.log(data)
  setData(1)
  
  return <button onClick={onClick}>button</button>
}
```

I don't know why the result came out like this.

Comment: In the first example does 1 printed twice when you press button once or you pressed twice?

Comment: I pressed button more than twice. 
If I press 10 times, the result is same.
@kennarddh

Comment: This is not in `<StrictMode>` @Phil

Comment: I got same result from your link @Phil

Comment: I've re-opened your question. Thanks for clarifying the problem

Comment: Does this helps - https://stackoverflow.com/a/74244136/11306028

Comment: calling `setData` is rerendering your component, which is causing the log function to be called

Comment: @DeanVanGreunen that should only happen when the value is different which for the 2nd click, it isn't

Comment: Hmm.. Thank you for your sincere answer! @Phil

Comment: @Phil even if the value is the same, it will still cause it to rerender

Answer (score 3):

This is React's expected behaviour. React tries to bail out of useless renders. But there might be times that it cannot judge it and would re-render anyway to be safe.

From the [legacy docs](https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#bailing-out-of-a-state-update):

> Note that React may still need to render that specific component again before bailing out. That shouldn’t be a concern because React won’t unnecessarily go “deeper” into the tree. If you’re doing expensive calculations while rendering, you can optimize them with useMemo.

Look at this [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/bold-glitter-forked-l8tr2p?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.js%3A25%2C20). Here I have updated your code to add a child component. As you can see even though there is an `un-necessary' re-render on the parent. The update is not going deeper into the tree.

Answer (score 1):

Adding some extra logging shows what's going on...

```jsx
export default function App() {
  const [data, setData] = useState(0);
  const renderCountRef = useRef(0);
  renderCountRef.current++;

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("data changed to", data);
  }, [data]);

  console.log("body data: ", data);
  console.log("body renderCount: ", renderCountRef.current);
  const onClick = () => {
    setData(1);
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={onClick}>button</button>
      <pre>renderCount = {renderCountRef.current}</pre>
      <pre>data = {data}</pre>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit bold-glitter]

You can see that clicking the button a second time causes the following to be logged

> ```
> body data: 1
> body renderCount: 3
> ```

However the displayed `renderCountRef.current` doesn't move beyond `2`.

React appears to be executing a render but then determines nothing needs to change and discards the result.

From [the (legacy) docs](https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#bailing-out-of-a-state-update)

> ##### Bailing out of a state update
>
> If you update a State Hook to the same value as the current state, React will bail out without rendering the children or firing effects.

Just like how `<StrictMode>` causes your effect hooks to execute multiple times, your app should be resilient to extra renders.

Comment: Thanks @Tushar. Would be nice if there was a https://react.dev equivalent for that doc link

Comment: This result is really interesting! Thank you!!

Comment: @Phil i have to find it. Wrote an answer myself to demonstrate that it really does not go deep inside the render tree.

Comment: @TusharShahi get's my vote!