No strict mode - Why does my React component render three times when I click a button multiple times?
I have a simple React component that uses a state hook. The initial state is false, and when a button is clicked, the state is set to true. I have a console.log statement in the component to log when it renders.
Here is my code:
import { useState } from 'react';

function App() {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(false);

  function changeState() {
    setValue(true);
  }

  return (
    <>
      {console.log('rendered!')}
      <button onClick={changeState}>Click</button>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;

When I click the button multiple times, I see the message "rendered!" logged three times in the console. I expected it to be logged twice - once for the initial render, and once for the re-render after the state change. Can anyone explain why it's being logged an extra time?

I forgot to add that i am not using in strict mode. i modified the title.
This is the output
rendered! App.jsx:27
rendered!App.jsx:27
rendered! App.jsx:27

Does this answer your questions -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77804251/extra-console-log-from-component-body-despite-state-not-changing/77804666#77804666.
This behaviour is documented in react, but the update does not go deeper into the tree

Do you mean this?
In this case, React is not able to judge the changes hence rendering.
I also found this one.
If the new value you provide is identical to the current state, as determined by an Object.is comparison, React will skip re-rendering the component and its children. This is an optimization. Although in some cases React may still need to call your component before skipping the children, it shouldn’t affect your code.
https://react.dev/reference/react/useState

Yes. That is the same thing mentioned in the new updated docs. In the above linked question I have posted a demo also.

I tried your code in React 18 and I do not have this problem.
In older version, more re-renders can be expected. This shouldn't be an issue as the reconciliation process is pretty swift
https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#bailing-out-of-a-state-update
What version of React are you using?

"react": "^18.2.0",
"react-dom": "^18.2.0"
Try this
https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/wonderful-jennings-wshkq6

This is not happening with 18.0.0
https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/relaxed-zhukovsky-lztp8r
