Confuse about render process when using useRef in React
Here is the testing code:
function Page() {
  const ref = useRef(null)
  const [show, setShow] = useState(false);
  const [refHasValue, setRefHasValue] = useState(false);

  console.log(ref, show, refHasValue);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (ref.current) {
      setRefHasValue(true); 
    }
  }, [ref.current]);

  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={() => setShow(true)}>Show</button>      
      {show && <div ref={ref}>Hello</div>}
      {refHasValue && <p>Ref has value</p>}
    </>
  );
}

Here is the console log result when I running this code snippet, here is the demo

{current: null} false false (Initial Render)
{current: null} true false (After I click the “Show” button)
{current: div} true false (After I click the “Show” button again)

I know the logic behind the first log. It is because the element has not been initialized, also all the other two state values is false
I know the logic behind the second log as well: After the click action modify the show value to true, the DOM shows up.
But I don’t know the logic behind the third log: Why is it clickable? The state show has been modified in the previous step, also “useEffect” has no impact here because it monitors the ref value, so refHasValue can not be updated. Since no state changed in this round, no render happened in the browser, why was something still printed out?

Here is a more simpler version demo

"useRef is a React Hook that lets you reference a value that’s not needed for rendering" You seem to need it for rendering. May you consider not relying on the ref current value?

After trying it out, I'm confused by this too. On the second button click there's no re-render (expected), no useEffect call (expected), but still a console log as if it did re-render. No strict mode either.. My guess is that it's still something going on like Strict Mode where React is re-calling the function even though it's not truly re-rendering

If you are concerned about the third render. This is the reason:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77804251/extra-console-log-from-component-body-despite-state-not-changing/77804666#77804666

Here is a demo which shows that the render does not go down the three. Check TestRenderer component Codepen: https://codepen.io/tusharshahi/pen/mdgaZPY?editors=1011

Why is it clickable? it will always be clickable. Its click should have no effect ideally.  I don’t know the logic behind the second log as well: -> do you want help here too?
